# VARX model on non -stationary timeseries

Tags: time-series, stationarity, vector-autoregression

I am going through the lecture notes on VARX by Dr Tsay Pg 11-22 [Link](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/mts/sp2017/lec7-17.pdf)

Plot of endogenous and exogenous series shows that these are not stationary. [image: Figure 6.6 in lecture notes]

Pg 15 shows lag 2 VAR model is fit at level. Not transformation or preprocessing is performed to make the series stationary. $m1=VARX(zt,2,xt,1)  \text{  #Full model estimation}$

Can we fit VARX at level for forecasting purpose when using exog series? How to explain the model fit at level to the governance team when most of the text suggest to fit VARX on stationary series?

My second question: Is algorithm of VARX can be explained as 2 step process: 
1) Regression of endog variable using exog as predictors.
2) Fit VAR on residual obtained during the regression.

Comment: Dear @Richard Hardy. Thankyou for the edit. Could you please provide your opinion on my query? I am getting a good forecast on fitting VARX at level as compared to fitting stationary one difference of series

Comment: Dear June, I would have already done that if I had the time and energy for that. I hope someone else can help you with your question.